# cakephp get schema for list of tables

Tags: cakephp

Is there an easy way in cakephp to get an array of tables schema for a list of specific tables? For example, i want a table schema for table a, b, d, f, and z; Also, is there a way to get a schema array of all the tables?

Comment: All tables can be dumped by using the `cake schema generate -f` command on the Cake Console. Not sure about specific tables though.

Comment: is there anyway to invoke this in a controller?

Comment: You could probably use the CakeSchema class for that: http://api20.cakephp.org/class/cake-schema

Comment: any chance on getting an example to use? :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get a datasource, by:

```
$db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
```

or

```
$db =& $this->User->getDataSource(); // or any other model
```

Then you can get all the tables by calling:

```
$db->listSources()
```

And get the schema for a table, say "products"

```
$db->describe('products');
```

However, passing a string to `describe` is **only in CakePHP 2.0**, 1.3 requires a model object.

Comment: i'm using 1.3 so I could just do $this->loadModel($modelname); $db->describe($this->$modelname) right?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept. This worked like a charm!

Comment: for 3.x it's a bit different: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/schema-system.html#schema-collections

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
pr($this->Model->schema());
```

Answer (score 0):

Within any table model you should be able to acess the current instance:

```
$this->getConnection()->getSchemaCollection()->listTables();
```