# List all tables in cakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, database-schema, cakephp-3.0

I have been trying to work this one out. In cakePHP 2 I could use:

```
$tables = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->listSources();
```

But in CakePHP 3.x I can't work out what to use?
I have looked at the link [cakephp get schema for list of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055996/cakephp-get-schema-for-list-of-tables)

Unfortunately it doesnt help with cakePHP 3.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can get list of table in cakephp3 using very similar pattern as

```
$tables = ConnectionManager::get('default')->schemaCollection()->listTables();
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.
Try using the code below

```
TableRegistry::exists($model);
```