# Cake 3.x: List all models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to get a list of all models of my application (including plugins).

In Cake 2 you could use `App::objects('Model');`. How am I able to do this in cake 3.x?

Thanks!

Bob

Comment: You can list tables in our schema like here: You can get the list of tables here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/schema-system.html#schema-collections, but for listing models am not sure of that yet. You may need to use php code such as `get_declared_classes(), see question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225971/is-it-possible-to-get-list-of-defined-namespaces

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all tables in cakePHP 3.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255196/list-all-tables-in-cakephp-3-x)

Comment: @BayezidAlam It's not a duplicate because it's not about tables ;)

Comment: @antoniovassell Thank you for your suggestion, however it doesn't look clean ;). I know that getting a table-list is possible, but I really need models ;)

Comment: Models do not exist in Cake 3. You'll want a list of Table classes.

Comment: Tables are stored under `Models` so that's why I call them models ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps, but it should give you about all the information you're going to be able to get.  To the point of the commenter(s), there aren't really "Models" in CakePHP 3 - there are Tables and Entities.

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

// ...

$tables = ConnectionManager::get('default')->schemaCollection()->listTables();
foreach($tables as $key => $table) {
    $tableData = TableRegistry::get($table);
    debug($tableData);
}
```

Returns this for each table:

```
object(App\Model\Table\PhotosTable) {

'registryAlias' => 'photos',
'table' => 'photos',
'alias' => 'photos',
'entityClass' => '\Cake\ORM\Entity',
'associations' => [
    (int) 0 => 'tags',
    (int) 1 => 'categorized'
],
'behaviors' => [
    (int) 0 => 'Timestamp',
    (int) 1 => 'Sluggable'
],
'defaultConnection' => 'default',
'connectionName' => 'default'

 }
```

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for your suggestion. However, this approach will not work properly, because some tables will be used by plugins. Getting the model with `TableRegistry::get($table)` won't see if it's used by a plugin ;).

Comment: And this only works if the name of the table is the same as the related classname e.g. 'PostsTable' and 'posts' table.